# Do I have an option to access all threads running in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad, nsthread

I have used `detachNewThreadSelector` method to create threads in my app. At some point of time, when user is logged out from the app, I should kill all running threads in the app. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a thread with `detachNewThreadSelector` you pretty much have to let it finish by itself :(

A better option if you want to be able to control background tasks would be `NSOperationQueue` - with this you can pass cancel messages to operations.

([Apple docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html))

---

EDIT : If you don't want to use NSNotificationCenter, you could set a flag that your background threads periodically check and if it's set they will exit themselves. However, you would have to be careful about thread safety there :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "normal" NSThread constructor - (id)initWithTarget:... and save your thread object.
2. Or save thread objects somewhere after thread start.
3. Don't save thread objects at all, just use some separate flags that you'll check in your threads and exit them.

Comment: I have called Cancel on a thered, even though it didn't stop.

Comment: Of course it will not, have you read the docs? There's no way to kill a thread, you should set a flag (that's what cancel method effectively does) and check that flag in your thread.